# VueJS set base URL headers

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vuex

I'm developing a system whose authentication based on tokens.

I successfully caught and saved the `idToken` inside the `store.js`.

Then I create a `getter` to return this `idToken` value:

```
returnToken(state) {
  return state.idToken
}
```

Up to this everything is okay. I can see `idToken` value in both places (`state` and `getters`) through **vue developer tools.**

Then in the **main.js** I added a computed property:

```
export default {
  computed: {
    returnToken(){
      return this.$store.getters.idToken
    }
  }
}
```

and Finally I added

> ```
> axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']=this.returnToken
> ```

But `Authorization` header is `undefined` in the developer tools network.

How do I fix this and How do I know check whether or not it successfully reach to the main.js?

Comment: You named your getter `returnToken` and in computed property you are accessing using `this.$store.getters.idToken`.   So change your ccomputed property to return `this.$store.getters.returnToken`

Comment: @VamsiKrishna I think you have the correct answer

Comment: I tried that but result is the same

Comment: `this.$store.state.idToken`

Comment: Where is that axios.defaults.headers ... located? is it inside main.js?

Comment: Yes It is inside main js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a **getter** as follows:

```js
returnToken(state){
    return state.idToken;
}
```

Then in the component, [**access the getter** using](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html):

```js
export default {
    computed: {
        returnToken(){
            return this.$store.getters.returnToken; // was getters.idToken
                                    // ^^^^^^^^^^^ --- changed this part
        }
    }
}
```

**OR**, in the component, [**access the state** using](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/state.html):

```js
export default {
    computed: {
        returnToken(){
            return this.$store.state.idToken;  // was getters.idToken
                            // ^^^^^ ------------ changed this part
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried both of this but it says idToken is undefined as well as it isn't a component it's main.js file. Is that may be the problem?

Comment: Try: `store.state.idToken`